# Compiling ICU Library for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libxml2, icu

I wanted to compile libxml2 for my Android Project, but it seems that libxml2.so requires libicu.so to function correctly. I saw a couple of sites about how to compile and create libicu.so file. I downloaded the source from https://github.com/android/platform_external_icu4c and read the instructions. I could compile for Linux (Ubuntu) successfully. But I have no idea how I should cross compile for Android. I saw a couple of stack over flow questions but they seem a bit confusing for me.

Can someone guide me how i can build the ICU Library for Android ?

Comment: As there is already discussion around this I suggest you either ask specifics or comment there.

Comment: @NuSkooler I would be more than glad to ask or comment there but my question is more like a general question Getting Started type. While whichever Stackoverflow questions i found all were specialized type of questions. Did not know where my query would fit so did not comment there to avoid negative marking.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android do you run? The library might already be installed. For example, in my Android 4.0.3, the following libraries are already there: `/system/lib/libicui18n.so`, `/system/lib/libicuuc.so`.

Comment: Libraries `libicui18n.so` and `libicuuc.so` are also available in `/system/lib` in my 2.3.4 phone. Maybe they are always there in Android (since that version at least)?

Comment: Belongs to the libraries that you shouldn't trust. The most recent one now broke backward compatibility. Bundle with our products